# Query String missing when redirecting with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following express js route which helps in redirecting to the given URL.

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.query.url;
  res.redirect(url);
});
```

It's working fine. But the problem is, somehow the passed query strings is getting cut off for no reason.

Example:

This is what I'm actually passing.

```
http://localhost:3000/?url=https://google.com/?abc=123&def=456&aaa=098
```

After redirecting whatever after the first query string goes missing.

It's appearing like this.

```
https://google.com/?abc=123
```

Not sure why `&def=456&aaa=098` goes missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) functions.

For example:

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.query.url;
  res.redirect(decodeURIComponent(url));
});
```

Note that the `url` parameter must be encoded in the actual URL.
Your URL should look something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/?url=https://google.com/%3Fabc%3D123%26def%3D456%26aaa%3D098
```